# ModuleNotFoundError occurred when kicking off python multiprocessing pool workers

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, python-module

In my project, I have a long list of trades to be priced so I break it into chunks and delegate them to multiprocessing#Pool to process. Let's say the wrapping class is called *Valuation*, the method is *pool_calculate*(), which looks like:

```
    multiprocessing.freeze_support() 
    p = multiprocessing.Pool()  # default is a number of processes equal to the number of CPU cores
    results = p.map(self.pooled_valuation_tasks, chunks)
    p.close()
    p.join()
```

The problem is that we have to import an in-house module, say, *magic*, for all pricing.

```
import magic
class Valuation(object):
    ....
```

It seemed that the module is not propagated into the pool workers, the error messages look like:

```
Process SpawnPoolWorker-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\opt\magic0.0.46\PythonVenv\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "c:\opt\magic0.0.46\PythonVenv\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "c:\opt\magic0.0.46\PythonVenv\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 108, in worker
    task = get()
  File "c:\opt\magic0.0.46\PythonVenv\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 337, in get
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(res)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'magic.rec'
```

anyone can help?

**Update**:

To provide more details in response to some questions from the comments:

this is how I instantiate the class and call the func:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   valu = Valuation(...)
   valu.pool_calculate(...)
```

Comment: It's tough to answer this without a complete example to reproduce the problem. A couple of thoughts: Are you importing `magic` at the top-level of the module? Are you protecting the creation of the `multiprocessing.Pool()` with a `if __name__ == "__main__":` guard?